# Разделение данных таблицы ms sql

Tags: sql

Есть ли возможность разделить **одну строку**, на несколько?

---

(Почему-то не создаются таблицы, хотя в форматировании всё правильно)

---

[image: Данные]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as
(select * from (values(1,'A',3,1),(2,'B',2,1)) x(id,name,count,cnt))
,rec as
(select * from t
union all
select 1,name,count, cnt+1 cnt from rec
where cnt<count
)
select row_number() over(order by name) id, name, 1 count from rec
;
```

Comment: Отлично, теперь я знаю, что такая возможность есть. Но переделать под свой пример не получается из-за `cnt`, так как такая колонка у меня есть. Подскажите, как должен выглядеть запрос. Таблица `TableA`, колонки `[id], [gtin] ,[batch], [prod_name], [federal_subject_name], [city], [area], [inn], [owner], [packing_inn], [emitent], [cnt]`. А также `over(order by name)` нет уникального значения. Единственное отличие `id` и `cnt`